# Separate two elements from the CSS without getting into proprietary code

Tags: css

I would like to separate "number of pieces" from "price of the article" in the "nouveaux puzzles" box at http://www.puzzles-et-jeux.com with either a space between them or a line break. The proprietary code generating the catalog lists [##box_complement?champ=NOUVEAUTES&nb_products_affiche=4&nb_products=4&dimension=200x200&fields=designation;famille;prix] and I don't think it can be modified, but there might be a way to change it within the CSS. Thank you

Comment: looks like you're plugging that site to me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Space between:

```
span.famille { margin-right:5px; }
```

Line break:

```
span.famille { display:block; }
```